# About vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

Show that if a vector space contains two elements, then it contains infinitely many.

I have a question to proove but my brain couldnt work this out can you please show how to prove this argument?

Comment: That's not actually true, so that's a problem. But perhaps you are working over certain kinds of vector spaces (for example, over the real numbers?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your field is finite and $V$ is the vector space, then it will have finitely many elements unless $V$ is infinite dimensional over the field.

On the other hand, if your field $F$ is infinite, and you have two distinct elements, one of them is nonzero: call it $v$. Then $\{\lambda v\mid \lambda \in F\}$ is infinite. (See why? You basically have to demonstrate that $\alpha\neq\beta\implies \alpha v\neq \beta v$.)

Comment: of course! thank you. you have to have a non zero vector and a zero vector for your space to be a vector space I should've seen that :/

Answer (score 0):

Any finite field is a vector space over itself. So above hypothesis is not true.

Comment: this might be an error then I'll probably go to my lecturer for this problem thank you but just in case I'll wait a bit more.